# Omnisharp can't find document for my file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

When I run Visual Studio Code and look at my output in the omnisharp log omnisharp is giving me this error:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 12/30/2020, 7:59:17 PM
    Target: c:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\C#\brackeysTutorial\brackeysTutorial.sln

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: c:\Users\Joshua\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.9\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 31196

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.2.9200.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 2 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: Visual Studio Community 2019 16.6.30320.27 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
            2: StandAlone 16.8.0 - "c:\Users\Joshua\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.9\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: Visual Studio Community 2019 16.6.30320.27 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in 'c:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\C#\brackeysTutorial'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Detecting projects in 'c:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\C#\brackeysTutorial\brackeysTutorial.sln'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in 'c:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\C#\brackeysTutorial'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 110
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.BlockStructureWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 140
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'c:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\C#\brackeysTutorial' on host 11668.
[info]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionService
        Could not find document for file c:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\C#\brackeysTutorial\Program.cs
[info]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionService
        Could not find document for file c:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\C#\brackeysTutorial\Program.cs
[info]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionService
        Could not find document for file c:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\C#\brackeysTutorial\Program.cs
[info]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionService
        Could not find document for file c:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\C#\brackeysTutorial\Program.cs
[info]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionService
        Could not find document for file c:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\C#\brackeysTutorial\Program.cs
```

I tried reinstalling the C# extension and it didn't help. I have "omnisharp.path" set to "latest" in my settings.json file, and I have "omnisharp.useGlobalMono" set to "always". Please help!

Answer (score 0):

windows does not like software running out of or touching the one drive folder.

Try moving your project and assets into your documents folder and running it from there.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue on Linux Ubuntu